# How to disable Bootstrap Toggle-Buttons on click at another Toggle Button?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, toggle

I need help with my code. I've looked a lot on the internet, but the code i have found doesn't work.

I have two toggle buttons (hg-geraet-b, hg-geraet-v).

The button "hg-geraet-v" should not be selectable and deactivated by default.
If the button "hg-geraet-b" is pressed (Toggle to activate), the button "hg-geraet-v" should be selectable.
If you now check the button "hg-geraet-v" to activate, the button "hg-geraet-b" should be reset and no longer be selectable.

Which Java code do I have to insert into the < script>...< /script> at the end of my code, so that this works?

```html
<div>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="product" class="card-input-element" />
<div class="card text-center">
 <p>Header</p>
  <div class="card-body">
  <p class="card-text">Kategorie</p>
  
  <div><input id="hg-geraet-b" type="checkbox" data-style="w-100" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="outline-secondary" data-toggle="toggle" data-size="sm" data-on="Beraten" data-off="Beraten">
  </div>
  <div><input onclick="hg-geraet-v" type="checkbox" data-style="w-100" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="outline-secondary" data-toggle="toggle" data-size="sm" data-on="Verkauft" data-off="Verkauft">
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const hgGeraetB = document.querySelector('#hg-geraet-b'),
  hgGeraetV = document.querySelector('#hg-geraet-v');

const handleChange = () => {
  if (hgGeraetB.checked) {
    hgGeraetV.disabled = false;
  } else if (hgGeraetV.checked) {
    hgGeraetB.checked = false;
    hgGeraetB.disabled = true;
  }
}

hgGeraetB.addEventListener('change', handleChange)
hgGeraetV.addEventListener('change', handleChange)
```

```html
<div>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="product" class="card-input-element" />
    <div class="card text-center">
      <p>Header</p>
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">Kategorie</p>f

        <div><input id="hg-geraet-b" type="checkbox" data-style="w-100" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="outline-secondary"  data-size="sm" data-on="Beraten" data-off="Beraten">
        </div>
        <div><input id="hg-geraet-v" type="checkbox" disabled='true' data-style="w-100" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="outline-secondary" data-toggle="toggle" data-size="sm" data-on="Verkauft" data-off="Verkauft">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. I have insert it and now are both Buttons disabled and deactivated.

First: The Button "hg-geraet-b" must selectable, on click ist must make the other button "hg-geraet-v" visible.

Second: When I click On the Button "hg-geraet-v", the Button "hg-geraet-b" must change toe default and make deactivatet.

Ithink there is an little Typing error or something.

Comment: I have insert the code in the head-area in my scribt tags.
I only import the jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js - Need I more thinks? I hope I have Insert it Right. But my Buttons are deactivatet, also i think the code runs.

Comment: Don't use the slim version and If you're adding your JS in head. be sure to have your code wrapped in `$(document).ready(() => { // code goes here })`

Comment: I'll check and update the code later. I only have a few minutes per day, this has extended my time available.